# geometrical representation of minimum norm least square solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given three equations in two variables is like giving a triangle on the plane. Now I want to describe the minimum norm least square solution  $x=A^+b$ in terms of the geometry of the triangle.  Here $A+$ denotes Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.

I consider that in the equations the sum squares of the coefficients are 1. So, for the system of equations
\begin{cases}a_{11}x+a_{12}y=b_1\\a_{21}x+a_{22}=b_2 \\a_{31}x+a_{32}y = b_3 \end{cases},
how can I describe the point $A^+b$  geometrically?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra**

A matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{3\times 2}_{\rho}$, induces a *row space* and a *column space* with the orthogonal decomposition:
$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbf{C}^{2} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \\
%
  \mathbf{C}^{3} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}
%
\end{align}
$$

**Method of least squares**

Given an appropriate data vector $b\in\mathbb{C}^{3}$, the linear system
$$
\mathbf{A} x = b
$$
has a least squares solution defined by
$$
 x_{LS} = \left\{
 x\in\mathbb{C}^{2} \colon
\big\lVert
 \mathbf{A} x - b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2}
\text{ is minimized}
\right\}
$$
The least squares solution is computed using
$$
 x_{LS} = 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+} b} +
\color{red}{ 
\left(
\mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A}
\right) y}, \quad y \in \mathbb{C}^{n}
\tag{1}
$$

**Decomposing the data vector**

The least squares solution resolves the data vector into $\color{blue}{range}$ and $\color{red}{spaces}$ as
$$
 b = \color{blue}{b_{\mathcal{R}}} + \color{red}{b_{\mathcal{N}}}
$$
The portion of the data vector in the range space is
$$
\color{blue}{x_{LS}} = 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+}b} =
\color{blue}{b_{\mathcal{R}}}
$$

Read a bit more: [How does minimum squared error relate to a linear system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006275/how-does-minimum-squared-error-relate-to-a-linear-system/2253674#2253674), [Finding the null space of a matrix by least squares optimization?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235236/finding-the-null-space-of-a-matrix-by-least-squares-optimization/2238813#2238813)

---

To draw specific diagrams, pick the case where the rank of the matrix is $\rho=1$.

**Column space**

The minimization occurs in the column space.

[image: column]

**Row space**

The set of least squares minimizers in (1) is an affine space, represented by the dashed red line in the figure below.

The operator $\color{red}{ 
\left(
\mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A}
\right) y}$ projects the vector $y$ onto the null space $\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)}$.

The blue point $\color{blue}{x_{LS}}$ is the pseudoinverse solution
$$
\color{blue}{x_{LS}} =
\color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+}b}
$$
and is the solution of the minimum norm. This is where the affine space of the least squares minimizers $x_{LS}$ intersects the range space, $\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$.

[image: row]